# convert date string with hour and minutes to seconds in bash

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a sample string that contains YYYYMMDDHHMM format.
I am trying to convert it into seconds but getting below error.

```
[vagrant@CentOS-Seven ~]$ export SAMPLE_DATE=201812051147
[vagrant@CentOS-Seven ~]$ echo $SAMPLE_DATE
201812051147
[vagrant@CentOS-Seven ~]$ date -d $SAMPLE_DATE
date: invalid date ‘201812051147’
[vagrant@CentOS-Seven ~]$
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56843/187122 and https://askubuntu.com/a/914342/606503 to accept your date format as input. Use `+%s` to convert to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/how-do-you-specify-a-format-for-the-input-to-date/56843#56843) `date` has not option to specify the input format. Therefore you have to convert your input into a format that is accepted by `date`. The `sed` command in the following command converts  `201812051147` to `2018-12-05 11:47`.
To convert a date to seconds, use the output format `+%s`.

```
$ input=201812051147
$ date -d "$(sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5/' <<< "$input")" +%s
1544010420
```

Please not that the output depends on your systems timezone. You can change the timezone by setting the `TZ` environment variable.

By the way: You don't have to export your variable in this case. Also, the convention for naming variables in bash is to use lowercase letters. By convention only special variables are written in all caps. Using variable names written in all caps could lead to a name collisions with these variables.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently separating date and time parts with a space is enough, so:

```
$ echo 201812051147 | 
  sed -E 's/(.{8})(.{4})/\1 \2/' | 
  date -f - +"%s"
```

Output:

```
1544003220
```

Comment: Interesting. In that case you could even boil it down to `sed -E 's/.{8}/& /'` or `sed 's/....$/ &/'`.

Comment: Yes and no. it seems to fail if the seconds are there so they should be cleaned off with something like `sed -E 's/(.{8})(.{4}).*/\1 \2/'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "touch" command to assign that date to a file and then print it using "date", try this:

```
touch -t 201812051147 tmpfile ; date -r tmpfile +%s ; rm -f tmpfile
```